# Inline Class Priority

Tags: html, class

Simple Question; if I give an element two classes, i.e:

```
<div class="class-1 class-2 ..."></div>
```

Is there any hierarchy between the classes - like from left to right - or are the properties randomly overridden?

Answer (score 0):

The class that will be seen last by the browser during execution of your style tag or style sheet will override the other class.

So there is no left to right hierarchy when applying classes on an element.

Answer (score 0):

Inline order doesn't matter, but if your class-2 will override class-1 if it.

So it depends only on order in declaration, but not in the assignment.